# to create a batch file which reads a .txt file and outputs the required lines onto another .txt file

Tags: batch-file

I am having an input text file with a word(say hi & hello ) and rest numbers in every line . I need to read the entire file and output only the lines with hi (not hello) onto another text file using a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /i "hi " "text_file.txt">file2.txt
```

c[heck FIND and FINDSTR commands](http://ss64.com/nt/).

Answer (score 1):

```
findstr /i "\<hi\>" input.txt > output.txt
```

will find "hi" as a word, so "c**hi**nese" would not be found.