# advanced text searching windows command line utility

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

Does there exist a command line utility for Windows that can search text more sophisticated than FIND and FINDSTR? Something that will find all lines of text that contain specified keywords no matter the order of words?

For example, if the keywords are "Happily Ever After" it should find lines containing "Ever After Happily" and "If ever that happens after today, she will happily embrace it", but not "happily together".

Comment: So you are saying it has to find all three search terms in a line.

Comment: @Squashman Yes, indeed.

Comment: One find command for each search term and pipe the output of each find to the next find.

Comment: @Squashman Could you write an example?

Comment: And by the way it should match whole words only. It must not find "everlasting" or "afterward".

Comment: `should match whole words only`: `findstr` can [do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30234655/2152082)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type search.txt | findstr /i /r "\<happily\>" | findstr /i /r "\<ever\>" | findstr /i /r "\<after\>"
```

I used the test case...

search.txt:

```
Happily Ever After
Happily Ever After blah
blah Happily Ever After
Happily Ever blah After
If ever that happens after today, she will happily embrace it
happily together
happily
ever
after
happily ever
ever after
after happily
every happily afterwards
```

And that gives output:

```
Happily Ever After
Happily Ever After blah
blah Happily Ever After
Happily Ever blah After
If ever that happens after today, she will happily embrace it
```

above only.

Is this what you needed?

Comment: Read all the comments below the original question. You need to match whole words.

Comment: @Squashman I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Do you mean you only want the words on a line? Additionally, can you try the code on a input and explain what is wrong?

Comment: not me. The person asking the question. Do you not understand what it means to match a whole word? They gave a specific example in their comments. Your code will not work.

Comment: No, I'm not understanding what he or you means by matching a whole word. Do you want to remove the other words or something?

Comment: For instance, suppose the words "happily", "after" and "every" appear in a line, or "happily" "ever" "afterwards" - these will be found by your suggestion, but may not fit OP's requirements.

Comment: @Magoo I believe I understand now, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Mee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34980577/1012053), as it uses only native commands. However, it must read the file once for each word to search. This might slow things down if you add a large number of additional tests.

You could use my [JREPL.BAT hybrid Jscript/batch regex utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044), coupled with a bit of user supplied JScript, and get an efficient and robust solution that produces the result with a single pass through the text. JREPL is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the script, and can be accessed via `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged output.

Here is one possible solution using JREPL. I initialize variables `a`, `b`, and `c` to 0, then on each line I search for the required words, and each word sets a different variable to 1 if found. The replacement string must also replace the found word with itself. At the end of each line I disable printout of the line if the sum of `a+b+c <> 3`, and then I reset all three variables to 0 in preparation for the next line. The `/F` option at the end specifies that I am searching file "test.txt". I use line continuation to make the long command easier to read.

```
call jrepl "\b(?:(happily)|(ever)|(after))\b"^
           "if ($1) a=1; else if ($2) b=1; else c=1; $0"^
           /jbeg "var a=0,b=0,c=0"^
           /jendln "if (a+b+c!=3) $txt=false; a=b=c=0"^
           /j /i /f test.txt
```

Below is another solution that uses the same basic logic, except I use the /T option to simplify the code a bit. The /T option is similar to the Oracle Translate() function, or the unix tr command, or the sed y command.

```
call jrepl "\bhappily\b \bever\b \bafter\b"^
           "a=1;$0 b=1;$0 c=1;$0"^
           /jbeg "var a=0,b=0,c=0"^
           /jendln "if (a+b+c!=3) $txt=false; a=b=c=0"^
           /j /i /t " " /f test.txt
```